# pasting or merging transparent support image on jpeg image

Tags: c#, image-processing, png, transparency, jpeg

Im doing an image processing project using C# which requires to apply a rim to a existing car image.im still a very beginner to image processing. so far i have found the two center points of the wheels circles and radius of those circle using C#. but i have problem with attaching the the png/gif wheel image in the original image. i need to apply the png image in to wheel. any ideas how to archive this?

**Original Image:**

[image: Original image]

**Transparent wheel image:**

[image: Transparent wheel]

**Target result:**

[image: Target result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will draw the second image (wheelImage) on the first image(carImage) on the position specified with the size specified

```
    static void AppendWheel(Bitmap carImage, 
        Bitmap wheelImage, 
        float offsetLeft, 
        float offsetTop, 
        float width, 
        float height)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(carImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(wheelImage, offsetLeft, offsetTop, width, height);
        }
    }
```